# How to underline a string/text assigned Control.Text property in C# programmatically?

Tags: c#

How to underline (with Bold & italics) a string/text assigned Control.Text property in C#  *windows application*  programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the Font property.

You can't set the underline of the Font along with the other properties - as they're read only - so you'll need to create a new Font object and assign that to the Font property. There are several constructors that take the bold, italic & underline properties.

Answer (score 8):

Control provides property "Font". You can assign this by using the existing Font as prototype and define the desired style information.

This snippet makes all fonts of all top controls bold, underlined and italic:

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
{
   item.Font = 
      new Font
         (
            item.Font, 
            FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic
         );
}
```

Flo

Answer (score 2):

Say your control was a Label called myLabel

```
Font myFont = new Font(myLabel.Font,FontStyle.Bold|FontStyle.Italic|FontStyle.Underline);
myLabel.Font = myFont;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change the Control.Font property. The Font class has constructors for creating bold/italic/underlined Fonts.